# Meaning of "good-for-a-giggle"

Tags: meaning

I was reading a sentence:

> The Governor was a *good-for-a-giggle*, gullible man, that was all.

The english that my chapter deals with is "**BRITISH**", so i want to know the meaning of "good-for-a-giggle" from britishers because google gave me nothing so good.

**Note:** Meaning of:

> *for a giggle:* as a joke or prank; not seriously.(source:[CollinsDictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-a-giggle))

Comment: See [definition 2b](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student_clean?va=good)

Comment: Or weather it means same as "good for a laugh"? I hope yes!

Comment: "Mildly amusing", though whether because of the jokes he told or his silly behavior is hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction is similar  to  [good-for-nothing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/good-for-nothing) and the meaning is a  derogatory. The Governor was a laughable, gullible man.

Comment: I am wondering how you know that. It could mean any number of things. e.g. 1. He/she does a good line in stand-up comedy (including an impression of the laughing policeman) at the annual Christmas bash. 2. He/she has a devastating wit. 3. Ironically - he/she is a very serious and solemn-faced person. 4. He/she has completely lost control of the "staff" and attracts nothing but laughter and derision.

Comment: This “construction” really isn't relevant, as @Mari-LouA noted. The derogatory nature here is largely due to the context: the collocation with *gullible* implies that he is the *target* of much of the laughter; and the “that was all” clinches it by suggesting that was his entire value to the writer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say the idiom, **good-for-a-giggle**, is derogatory. Although its construction may resemble *good-for-nothing*, its meaning is very distant from that.

Instead, "good-for-a-giggle is undoubtedly related to the following

- [for a lark](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+a+lark+and+on+a+lark):  *for a joke; as something done for fun*
- [for a laugh](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+a+laugh): *for fun and amusement*

The expression suggests a person who is able to see the funny side of a situation, someone willing to share a joke but of the "mild" sort, not one that would seriously hurt or offend anyone. The governor in the story may be gullible but he sounds kind-hearted.

Substituting "laugh" with "giggle" was probably for alliterative purposes, so an alternative interpretation is that playing practical jokes (pranks) or tricks on him was enjoyable, i.e. good [fun] for a giggle.

Comment: Good-for-nothing is cited as an exemple of a common construction with “good-for-something”  which is used for good-for-a-giggle. I didn’t say their meaning is similar, just their “construction”. As for the meaning, the sentence does appear to convey a negative meaning as it stands. Probably more context should be added.

Comment: @user159691 *"Although its construction is similar..."* I said that, I didn't change what you wrote. I'm pointing out that the expression in the OP is not an insult. Saying someone is "laughable" is absolutely not the same as saying they are "good for a laugh".

Comment: Let's try again ... I misunderstood your stance. I think it *is* derogatory in this context, but I agree it's certainly not suggesting the target is a monster; and I wanted to back up your final assertion (*good for a laugh* usually isn't used in the sense of *laughable*).